# Insert into mysql using laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to add form data in mysql, so I have this:

criaEmpresa.blade.php

```
<form name="formCad" id="formCad" method="post" action="{{url('admin/addempresa')}}">
@csrf
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="empresa" id="empresa" placeholder="Empresa nome">
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="email da empresa">
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="site" id="site" placeholder="site da empresa">
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="logo" id="logo" placeholder="logo da empresa">
<br>
<input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Cadastrar">

</form>
```

my web.php

```
Route::get('/admin/criaempresa', [App\Http\Controllers\AuthController::class, 'Criaempresa'])->name('criaempresa');

Route::post('/admin/addempresa', [App\Http\Controllers\EmpresaInsertController::class, 'create'])->name('addempresa');
```

EmpresaInsertController.php

```
class EmpresaInsertController extends Controller
{
    
    public function insert(){
        $urlData = getURLList();
        return view('stud_create');
    }
    public function create(Request $request){
        $rules = [
            'empresa' => 'required|string|min:2|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255',
            'site' => 'required|string|min:2|max:255'
        ];
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(),$rules);
        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return redirect('admin/criaempresa')
            ->withInput()
            ->withErrors($validator);
        }
        else{
            $data = $request->input();
            try{
                $empresa = new EmpresaInsert;
                $empresa->nome = $data['empresa'];
                $email->email = $data['email'];
                $website->website = $data['website'];
                $student->save();
                return redirect('insert')->with('status',"Insert successfully");
            }
            catch(Exception $e){
                return redirect('insert')->with('failed',"operation failed");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and modal EmpresaInsert.php

```
class EmpresaInsert extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'empresas';
    public $timestamps = true;
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'nome', 'email','website', 'logo'
    ];
}
```

The problem is, nothing has been inserted... Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You are using like four different variables to access and set various properties of your model. You initialise it in `$empresa`, set `email` and `website` with `$email` and `$website` and store the model with `$student`. No exception will be thrown because you catch and supress them in your try-catch.

Comment: @Dan thanks a lot. I also got Class 'App\Http\Controllers\EmpresaInsert' not found any ideas?

Comment: That's a namespace issue, you forgot to `use App\Models\EmpresaInsert` (or whatever namespace your model is using)

Comment: fyi: instead of using the url in `action="{{url('admin/addempresa')}}"` you can use `action="{{route('addempresa')}}"` since you already named your route. This way, should you change the url you only have to change it once in your `web.php`

Answer (score 2):

your code is not actually updating the `EmpresaInsert` model here.  Change the following in your controllers try/catch block forom this...

```
$empresa = new EmpresaInsert;
$empresa->nome = $data['empresa'];
$email->email = $data['email'];
$website->website = $data['website'];
$student->save();
```

To this...

```
$empresa = new EmpresaInsert;
$empresa->nome = $data['empresa'];
$empresa->email = $data['email'];
$empresa->website = $data['website'];
$empresa->save();
```